# Apache Tomcat 7 The Requested Resource Is Not Available

Tags: tomcat7, server.xml

Newbie to Tomcat 7 and everything here so apologies if this is a simple error. I've looked through other questions and answers asking the same thing and nothing seems to pertain to my issue. I've updated Tomcat 5.5 to Tomcat 7. When accessing `http://localhost:80` I see the Tomcat 7 page perfectly fine so I'm guessing it's something in the URL that's being accessed.

I've installed Tomcat 7 and am trying to navigate to the URL `http://localhost/otcs/cs` but I keep getting the Request Resource is not available error. Below is my server.xml file.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.lang.String.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    com.opentext.servlet.client.LLServletClient.sendErrorPage(LLServletClient.java:249)
    com.opentext.servlet.client.LLServletClient.sendErrorPage(LLServletClient.java:208)
    com.opentext.servlet.client.LLServletClient.doGet(LLServletClient.java:122)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    com.opentext.servlet.filter.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:446)
```

Thanks for the help and I'm happy to give more information if needed.

Comment: Did you deploy your webapp? (You can check that via the manager) / What is the content of your webapp directory.

Comment: Hi MonoThreaded, I've deployed Tomcat, the service is started in the manager. The webapps directory has three folders, docs, manager and ROOT.

Comment: Your webapp (otcs I presume) needs to be deployed in `webapps/`. You can do this via the manager UI or by dropping your war in webapps. In the later case you may need to bounce Tomcat for the war to be deployed.

Comment: Thanks MonoThreaded, looks like we have some progress. I'm now getting the following error: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. 

This is followed by some exception code.

Comment: Hard to say without the error message, can you edit your question?

Comment: It seems to be a configuration problem while sending error message. Does your opentext instance require external data?

Comment: It's connecting to SEA servlet which then leads to a login page. Hope that helps.